# R console doesn't display unicode in a correct form

Tags: r, unicode, markdown, r-markdown

Our teacher asked us to use kable() function when finishing our data analysis problem. However, when I run the sample code the teacher provided, the unicode seems doesn't display correctly:

The sample code is the following:

```
n <- 100
x <- rnorm(n)
y <- 2*x + rnorm(n)
out <- lm(y ~ x)
library(knitr)
kable(summary(out)$coef,digits=2)
```

And the R console returns me the following graph:

```
|            | Estimate| Std. Error| t value| Pr(>&#124;t&#124;)|
|:-----------|--------:|----------:|-------:|------------------:|
|(Intercept) |    -0.07|       0.09|   -0.79|               0.43|
|x           |     2.05|       0.09|   22.81|               0.00|
```

The correct form of the last column should be **Pr(>|t|)** instead.

However, if change my code to:

```
kable(summary(out)$coef, format="latex",digits=2)
```

The returned result is:

```
\begin{tabular}{l|r|r|r|r}
\hline
  & Estimate & Std. Error & t value & Pr(>|t|)\\
\hline
(Intercept) & -0.07 & 0.09 & -0.79 & 0.43\\
\hline
x & 2.05 & 0.09 & 22.81 & 0.00\\
\hline
\end{tabular}
```

I suspect the problem is with the markdown system on my computer. Do anyone know how to fix this problem?

Answer (score 1):

I pasted the result from `kable(summary(out)$coef, format="latex",digits=2)` into a latex compiler and then ran it with the following change `Pr(\ge \mid t\mid)`. It worked. Sometimes R-Markdown doesn't do the job.